# How to set float:right in my case using css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with `<th>` tags but without any `<td>` tags. When it loads I will insert `<td>` tags using jquery so the table will have the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

Comment: @sanchitpatiyal because money based column should be in right side. What is the problem If i set right

Comment: if using Bootstrap, and it seems you are by the screenpic you posted (and deleted for some reason) you can use the `.text-right` class for the `<td>`s

Comment: @Liam neesan my bad I interpreted something else. Sorry :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try text-align: right;

Answer (score 1):

Use Text align right instead of float right

```
td.tdChequeAmount{
        text-align:right;
        padding-right:20px;
    }
    td.tdVendorBalance{
        text-align:right;
        padding-right:20px;
    }
    td.tdBalance{
        text-align:right;
        padding-right:20px;
    }
    td.tdStockValue{
        text-align:right;
       padding-right:20px;
    }
```